# How to get the row data by clicking the button in ag-grid

Tags: angular, typescript

I have written an angular code to display data in ag-grid. What I want is whenever I click on the button in particular cell I want to get the entire row data. But how my code is working is whenever I select the row I can get the data, whenever I deselect the row data is deleted. Can anyone help me to solve this? Here is my code:

file-process.component.ts

```
export class FileProcessComponent implements OnInit {

  searchResults : Array<String>;
  private selectedRows = [];
  selectionMode = "multiple";

  path = "http://localhost:3028/controller/getDirectoriesWithFiles";

  serialNumber = 1;
  getIndexValue(){
   return this.serialNumber++;
  }

  columnDefs =[
    {headerName:"S No", valueGetter: (args) => this.getIndexValue(),checkboxSelection : true,headerCheckboxSelection: false,
    headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,cellRenderer: 'selectedClient'}, 
    {headerName : 'Directory Name', field:'directory', sortable:true},
    {headerName : 'Options',cellRenderer : 'buttonRenderer' ,
     template : `
     <button type="button" (click)="this.deleteDir($event)">Delete</button>
     `
    }
  ]

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,private r : Router, private dp : DirPathComponent, private sf : ShowFilesComponent) {
    this.http.get(this.path).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.searchResults = data;
        console.log(this.searchResults);
        this.serialNumber = this.searchResults.length- this.searchResults.length+1;
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );

   }
   private params;
   dirPath = 'http://localhost:3028/controller/setDirectory';
   addDirectory(dirPath) : void{    
    this.params = new HttpParams();
    this.params = this.params.append('path', dirPath);
    this.http.get(this.dirPath, { params: this.params }).subscribe((data: any) => {

      this.http.get(this.path).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.searchResults = data;
        console.log(this.searchResults);
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
    });
   }

   onRowClicked(event){
    let temp = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.selectedRows.length; i++){
      if(this.selectedRows[i] == event.node.data.directory){
        this.selectedRows.splice(i,1);
        temp = 1;
      }
    }
    if(temp === 0){
      this.selectedRows.push(event.node.data.directory);
    }
  }
  deleteDir(event){
    // here I want which row is selected to delete
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

file-process.html:

```html
<div class="page-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <app-card [title]="file-process">
        <div style="float:left">
          <h4>Add directory</h4>
          <form>
            <input type="search" #path name="query">
            <button type="button" (click)="addDirectory(path.value)">Add</button>
          </form>
      </div>
      </app-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="page-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <app-card [title]="file-process">
          <ag-grid-angular
          style="width : 605px; height:250px;" 
          class="ag-theme-balham"
          [rowData]="searchResults" 
          [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
          [rowSelection]="selectionMode"
          [rowMultiSelectWithClick] = true
          (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)"
          >
          </ag-grid-angular>
        </app-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Just to confirm with you, everytime you click the button, do you want to get all selected rows? Or the row whereby you have just selected?

Comment: And are you referring to the `onRowClicked ` method?

Comment: I just want to get the row data where I click the button. Then I am calling the deleterDir(event) method

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your grid allows multiple selection, but I am unsure if you are trying to get only the selected row, or get all selected rows. You need to make the follow modifications:

On your .html, include the event binding for [rowSelected](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/) (you may read more about it on the API specifications):

```
<ag-grid-angular (rowSelected)="onRowSelect($event)" . . . . .></ag-grid-angular>
```

And on your component.ts, you can handle the row selection event. If you want to get the selected row only, you can simply do this:

```
onRowSelect(event) {
  console.log(event.data)
  // handle event.data which is the object with the selected row data
}
```

If you want to get all selected rows on selection, you can use [getSelectedRows](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#selection) which is part of the Ag-grid API. Do remember to initialise the grid API if you are to use it.

On your .html,

```
<ag-grid-angular (rowSelected)="onRowSelect($event)" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event) . . . . .></ag-grid-angular>
```

And on your component.ts,

```
onGridReady(params) {
  this.gridApi = params.api;
}

onRowSelect(event) {
  const selectedRows = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
  console.log(selectedRows);
}
```

Comment: What I want is when I click on the button deleteDir($event) is invoked and which row delete button is clicked that row data should be given to deleteDir($event)

Comment: Ok, so basically, when you click that button, it will trigger `deleteDir()`, and on the `deleteDir()` method, you want to get the data of the row that is being delete?

Comment: exactly @wentjun